# check a data.frame column (character) against 4 lists

Tags: r, list, character

I want to check a word (in a column in a data-frame) against 4 lists (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`):

```
if df$word is in a then df$code <- 1
if df$word is in b then df$code <- 2
if df$word is in c then df$code <- 3
if df$word is in d then df$code <- 4

if df$word is in a & b then df$code <- 1 2
if df$word is in a & c then df$code <- 1 3
if df$word is in a & d then df$code <- 1 4
if df$word is in b & c then df$code <- 2 3
if df$word is in b & d then df$code <- 2 4
if df$word is in c & d then df$code <- 3 4
```

etc.

What is the most efficient way to do so?

**Example**

```
df <- data.frame(word = c("book", "worm", "digital", "context"))

a <- c("book", "context")
b <- c("book", "worm", "context")
c <- c("digital", "worm", "context")
d <- c("context")
```

Expected output:

```
book    1 2
worm    2 3
digital 3
context 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: you can do it with grep and if else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
df <- data.frame(x =c("book", "worm","digital", "context"))

a <- c("book", "context")
b<- c("book", "worm", "context")
c <- c("digital", "worm", "context")
d <- c("context")


anno <- function(x){
  rslt = ""
  if (x %in% a) rslt =paste0(rslt," 1")
  if (x %in% b) rslt =paste0(rslt," 2")
  if (x %in% c) rslt =paste0(rslt," 3")
  if (x %in% d) rslt =paste0(rslt," 4")
  return(stringr::str_trim(rslt))
}

df$code <- sapply(df$x, anno)
df
#>         x    code
#> 1    book     1 2
#> 2    worm     2 3
#> 3 digital       3
#> 4 context 1 2 3 4
```

Created on 2018-08-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Comment: Thank you! just as a side question, I was thinking if I can consolidate df$code (as characters not as numbers) based on duplicates in df$word.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean, can you elaborate?

Comment: yes so if in df I have two rows for book (df$word is book for two rows) one has "1" in df$code and one has "2" in df$code. then if I could consolidate duplicates based on df$word so that the other column is added together (as charcaters and becomes "1 2".

Comment: @useR Sorry I still don't get it.  In the example data you provided, duplicated `book` in df$word will always generate the same `1 2` in df$code, did I miss anything here?

Comment: Your answer is 100% correct. I just wanted some additional information. never mind!

Answer (score 2):

We can use a double `sapply` loop where for every element in the data frame we check in `which` list element it is present and get the corresponding list number.

```
lst <- list(a, b, c, d)
df$output <- sapply(df$V1, function(x) paste0(which(sapply(lst, 
                           function(y) any(grepl(x,y)))), collapse = ","))

df
#       V1  output
#1    book     1,2
#2    worm     2,3
#3 digital       3
#4 context 1,2,3,4
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "book
      worm
      digital
      context")
```

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished in two steps:

1. Combine the four lists and reshape into long format
2. *Aggregate while joing* with `df`

using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
long <-setDT(melt(list(a, b, c, d), value.name = "word"))
long[setDT(df), on = "word", by = .EACHI, .(code = toString(L1))][]
```

> ```
>       word       code
> 1:    book       1, 2
> 2:    worm       2, 3
> 3: digital          3
> 4: context 1, 2, 3, 4
> ```